# The "assetic.filter_manager" service is private [Symfony 3.4]

Tags: symfony, assetic

First, I already saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49843298/user-deprecated-the-assetic-filter-manager-service-is-private-using-assetic).

When I try to update Symfony 3.3 to 3.4, I've got this deprecations :

```
User Deprecated: The "assetic.filter_manager" service is private, getting  it from the container is deprecated since Symfony 3.2 and will fail in 4.0. You should either make the service public, or stop using the container directly and use dependency injection instead.

User Deprecated: The "assetic.filter.cssrewrite" service is private, getting it from the container is deprecated since Symfony 3.2 and will fail in 4.0. You should either make the service public, or stop using the container directly and use dependency injection instead.

The "security.acl" configuration key is deprecated since Symfony 3.4 and will be removed in 4.0. Install symfony/acl-bundle and use the "acl" key instead.
```

1. I try adding this in `src/MyBundle/Resources/services.yml`:

```
services:
    Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\AsseticBundle:
        public: true
```

2. I installed acl-bundle. The file `config/security.yml`:

```
security:
    acl:
        connection: default
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: What exactly is the problem? That is only a deprecation warning, you don't have to care about it before upgrading to v4.0

Comment: It's to be able to update to 4.0 after that. I need to make my code "deprecation free"

Comment: @Mathi9121 you won't be able to upgrade to 4.0 and still use assetic. AsseticBundle itself is deprecated and won't be updated to fix the current deprecations. https://github.com/symfony/assetic-bundle

Comment: Then you should tell us what the problem is. What exactly does not work if you ignore these warnings and update to v4. Please add your answer to the question, not to the comment section, as it is highly important

Comment: What is your problem actually ?

Answer (score 5):

As you already know from comments, `assetic-bundle` is deprecated and therefore you're able to migrate on Symfony 4 without changing its service definition.

But generally speaking, if you want to override an external service configuration, you can implement a custom [CompilerPass](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/service_container/compiler_passes.html)

```
namespace AppBundle\DependencyInjection\Compiler;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\CompilerPassInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;

class OverrideServiceCompilerPass implements CompilerPassInterface
{
    public function process(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $container->getDefinition('assetic.filter_manager')->setPublic(true);
        $container->getDefinition('assetic.filter.cssrewrite')->setPublic(true);
    }
}
```

and add it to your bundle as stated in the [official documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/service_container/compiler_passes.html).

```
namespace AppBundle;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use AppBundle\DependencyInjection\Compiler\OverrideServiceCompilerPass;

class AppBundle extends Bundle
{
    public function build(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        parent::build($container);
        $container->addCompilerPass(new OverrideServiceCompilerPass());
    }
}
```

Refer to [Definition API](http://api.symfony.com/3.2/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Definition.html) documentation.